# Should suspended application in the background (by ctrl+z) still run or should it stop running?

Tags: bash, xorg, firefox, background-process, xinit

I run Firefox with command `xinit /path/to/firefox/binary` and it opens a display with Firefox running on it.

Then I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go back to console and then I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to suspend the Firefox into the background.

Then, I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to Firefox. I expect Firefox to be freezed or non-responsive, however I can still use Firefox with no problem. My expectation is based on my experience when sending other apps to background, like `wget`. When I send `wget` to background, the download process is stopped.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox puts itself in the background and detaches from your terminal if you run it from a terminal. Therefore pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is not really suspending Firefox, it probably suspends `xinit`.

`wget` and most commandline programs do not have this kind of detaching behaviour. GUI based programs like `gedit` start mostly like firefox and detach.

---

I looked if there was some option to prevent this from happening. `-foreground` seemed a likely option name, but that just pushes the firefox window to the foreground.

Comment: Firefox does not put itself in the background. If you run it with an instance already running, the new instance contacts the existing instance and exits immediately; but if you start a fresh instance, it stays in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does suspend the application, as in, it stops running until resumed with a SIGCONT (possibly sent through the `fg` or `bg` command in the shell). But…

You're running `xinit`, not `firefox`. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends a STOP signal to the application that's running in the foreground, not to other applications that it may have run. So you've only suspended `xinit` itself, and this doesn't affect the X11 session.

More precisely, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends a STOP signal to the foreground [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). This may involve more than one process, but the intent of process groups is that it's still morally a single unit for signalling purposes.

(The same holds for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and SIGINT, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> and SIGQUIT. On the other hand, SIGHUP when the terminal disappears is only sent to a single process: the session leader, normally the shell; shells in turn send SIGHUP to the jobs they launched.)

`xinit` runs both the X server and the client in their own process group, precisely so that you can suspend or kill it without killing the whole session. When you send it a catchable signal, it kills the X server, which in turns causes most X applications to exit — so pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does bring down the GUI session, but indirectly, not because every client and the server received a SIGINT due to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. On the other hand, `xinit` doesn't do anything particular on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, so that just suspends `xinit` and leaves the session alone, which is useful when you want to do something else in the terminal where you ran `xinit`.